# Replacing a word in a sentence using a form

Tags: javascript

(Edited version of my previous question) So i need to replace a word in a sentence, which i have figured out how to do by now. But it's not working in a form.

I'm giving the user 2 forms, 1 to input a word they want to replace in the sentence "Dit document is een lang document maar ook een simpel document". And another 1 to input a word they want to replace that word with.

The only error it's giving me, is that "woord" and "nieuwewoord" in line 9 are undefined. Which are references to the form.

```
<form vervangen='form'>
        <input type="text" name="woord" placeholder="Wat moet er weg?">
        <input type="text" name="nieuwewoord" placeholder="Wat moet er staan?">
        <input type="button" value="Vervang"
            onclick="document.write(tekstvr)">
        <script>
        var tekst =
        "Dit document is een lang document maar ook een simpel document";
        var tekstvr = tekst.replace(woord,nieuwewoord);
        </script>
```

I hope someone could help me! And i hope this isn't also another dupe (tried being more specific this time) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Which one is word input element and sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const tekstDiv = document.getElementById('tekst')
const tekst ="Dit document is een lang document maar ook een simpel document";
tekstDiv.innerHTML = tekst;
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
    const woord = document.getElementById('woord').value;
    const nieuwewoord = document.getElementById('nieuwewoord').value;
    tekstDiv.innerHTML = tekst.replace(woord,nieuwewoord);
});
```

```html
<input id="woord" type="text" name="woord" placeholder="Wat moet er weg?">
<input id="nieuwewoord" type="text" name="nieuwewoord" placeholder="Wat moet er staan?">
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Vervang">
<div id="tekst"></div>
```

Comment: Alright so i put this in my HTML, i can see in here that it's working but for me it's not. Probably should've mentioned it's in a HTML file.

https://imgur.com/gallery/u2GOpiV This is what i have. Not sure why it's not working

Comment: You need to put the javsscript inside <script>-tags. I.e: <script>CODE</script>

Comment: Yeah i think i got that, i shared a link in my previous reaction with a picture of what i got.

Comment: Sorry, i got it. Had the order wrong. 
Thanks so much for your help!